# where does a debugger saves the pointer to the next command in the code segment?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, exe

I am working on a challenge for my school and teacher. Basically they are given a .exe file that receives a password input and their goal is to break the password. They can use whatever they like to try and do it and I'm already working on some defense mechanisms. One thing I want to do is to prevent them from debugging the decompiled version of the .exe file(they will use Ghidra to reverse engineer it).

I know debuggers work by running the code one command after another, basically like a script. I thought of a possible(I hope) concept and thought about accessing the software's memory in order to be able to edit the value of the pointer to the next command on the debugger. 
Meaning if the debugger is now running a certain command line from the code, it must have stored a pointer to it somewhere, and perhaps I would be able to change the value of the pointer mid-run, to mess with the debugging process. Is there a way to know where a certain debugger stores the pointer value of the next command?

Comment: Why don't you give them an executable without the debugging information? You won't be able to prevent them reverse-engineering it though. The best you can hope for is obfuscation, perhaps red herrings too.

Comment: You might not have access to the debugger's data space, even if you knew the insides of every debugger they might be using.

Comment: @WeatherVane: There are some debugger-detection techniques, so you can write code like `if(debugger_present()) exit();` forcing someone to find that code and work around / skip over it before they can reach and single-step the actual password-checking code.  I'd google for `debugger detection`. 
 Although if it blocks for I/O right before verifying the password, attaching a debugger *at that point* is the obvious thing.  I guess you could do debugger detection again after that. Or maybe take the password as a command line arg.

Comment: A good way would be to not actually store the password in the software, look into a hashing function like djb2 and calculate the hash of the password then hash any input to the program and compare it to the stored hash. Hashes can't be easily reversed so it would be quite difficult to recover the password. If you do this then it doesn't matter if they attach a debugger and follow the code, they will only see something like if (hash(input) == 0xdeadbeef) but they won't know which input generates that hash without bruteforcing all possibilities.